# Overscan on 42" NEC

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, graphic-drivers

I just installed elementary Freya 0.3.2 on a Dell Optiplex 755, hooked up to a Overscan on 42" NEC monitor (TV). My DVI graphics card is an ATI Radeon 102-A771B.

My problem is overscan. I tried installing AMD catalyst, but fouled up.

I installed fglrx (ATI binaryX.org driver) but it wasn't useful.

Anyway I had to do a clean install, as I had a dead screen.

Using Ubuntu help pages, I was about to reinstall fglrx, but decided to try and get advice here.

I can cut and paste to the terminal, but am much more a GUI guy. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I took the video card out, I am just running the onboard video card now. Re-installed, problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

OK, for this particular monitor you need to get your remote or use the bottom buttons on the monitor. Press 'menu'. Scroll to 'OPTION 1' then 'RGB SELECT', then select 'DTV'. Exit out and turn your attention to your GUI.

Next, you need to get into the 'system settings' menu, then the 'display' option.

The blue box in the center of the page should say "NEC Corporation 42"

Click on the upper right hand corner of the blue mini-screen, on the gear icon.

2 options are there Resolution and rotation.

Click the drop down menu of resolution and click 1360 X 768 (16:9)

Unfortunately the 'apply' button will not be visible on your screen. 1st click outside of the 'resolution' box. Hit 'tab' 5 or 6 times, then hit enter.

You'll know you got it if the screen goes wonky for a moment and then you see the whole 'displays' gui. A dialogue box will start counting down as you need to choose 'keep the new resolution' (or somesuch statement.

The full beauty of elementary should now be ay your command.

P.S. I'm sure something similar will work for other overscan problems with HD and emulated HD TVs.

Good Luck